# What re the federal and Calif. solar tax credits or deductions for a solar power systems and batteries purchased in California in year 2019 and 2021?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, state-income-tax, california

Bought a new solar power system for my primary residence for $65k in July 2019.
Then moved this year and bought a $90k system Nov 2021.

I'm using Turbo Tax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... there is no California-specific solar tax credit. When people
> refer to the ‘California solar tax credit’, they are actually
> referring to the federal solar tax credit ...

https://www.solarreviews.com/blog/california-solar-incentives-calculator#california-solar-tax-credit